# Optimizing terrain rendering in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm currently rendering geological data, and have done so successfully with good results. To clarify, I input a matrix of elevations and output a single static mesh. I do this by creating a single plane for each elevation point, then, after creating all of these individual planes, merge them into a single mesh.

I've been running at 60 FPS even on a Macbook Air, but I want to push the limits. Is using a single `PlaneGeometry` as a heightmap as described in other terrain examples more efficient, or is it ultimately the same product at the end of the process?

Sorry for a general question without code examples, but I think this is a specific enough topic to warrant a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own tests that I spent a couple of days running, creating individual custom geometries and merging them as they are created is wildly inefficient, not just in the render loop, but also during the loading process.

The process I am using now is creating a single `BufferGeometry` with enough width and height segments to contain the elevation data, as described in [this article](http://blog.mastermaps.com/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs.html).